# How to display custom field data in posts?

Tags: wordpress

When we create a post and publish it, we get some thing like this (Posted on: August 8, 2015 / Comments: 2 comments / Categories: Videos) in the bottom part of the post. I want to add another thing to it, like for eg (Posted on: August 8, 2015 / Comments: 2 comments / Categories: Videos / Selfielink).

So i added a custom field called Selfie_link to the post. Now i want to display the value of selfie link (which is a link to a website) i have stored different url's for each posts.

This is my single.php(for editing single posts):

```
<?php 

    /**
     * Wp in Progress
     * 
     * @author WPinProgress
     *
     * This source file is subject to the GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE (GPL 3.0)
     * It is also available at this URL: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt
     */

    get_header(); 
    novalite_header_content();

?> 


<!-- start content -->

<div class="container content">

    <div class="row">

    <div <?php post_class(array('pin-article', novalite_template('span') , novalite_template('sidebar'))); ?> >

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            do_action('novalite_postformat');

$mykey_values=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Selfie_link', true);

    echo '<ul>';
        echo '<li>' . $name . '/' . $day .'</li>';
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() .         '</a></li>';?>
        <a href="<?php echo $mykey_values; ?>">Selfie Link</a>
    <?php echo '</ul>';
        ?>

        <div style="clear:both"></div>

    </div>

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; get_template_part('pagination'); endif;?>

    </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

My problem is i have stored value `www.youtube.com` for a selfie link and when i click on the link Selfie Link i get redirected to this link `192.168.1.3/~user/urshow_news/2015/08/13/rter/www.youtube.com`.

I thought i will be redirected to `www.youtube.com`. Why is it happening so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while adding the link add it as
https://www.youtube.com/

Comment: ok i added like this www.youtube.com, i should have added with https://   its working now.